# Set up distributed index using Hibernate Search and Lucene

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search, infinispan

Our application is using Hibernate Search for indexing some of its data. The application is running on two JBoss EAP 6.2 application servers for load distribution and failover. We need changes made on one machine to be immediately visible on the other. The index is a central part of the application and needs to be consistent with the database data. Completely rebuilding it takes a long time so it is important that it remains intact even in the case of a server crash. Also, the index is expected to grow too large to keep all of it in memory.

Our current solution is to use the standard filesystem directory with a shared filesystem (NFS) and the JGroups backend to ensure that only one server writes to a given index at any time. This works more or less, but sometimes we have problems with index updates taking very long (up to 20 seconds) or failing completely. Due to some other reasons we need to migrate away from the currently used file system, so we are evaluating alternatives for the current setup.

One thing we tried is the Infinispan directory with a file cache store for persistence, but we had some problems there regarding OutOfMemoryErrors (see also my post in the Infinispan forums https://developer.jboss.org/thread/253732). Also, performance was still not acceptable in our first tests (about 3 seconds for an index update with two clustered servers set up on my developer machine), though that may be due to configuration issues.

I think this is not such an uncommon requirement, but I couldn't find much information on best practices to implement it.

Who has experiences with similar setups? Does the Infinispan directory work for you? Can anybody suggest a working configuration or how to proceed to arrive at one? What alternatives have you tried and which work?

Comment: Newer versions of Hibernate Search and Infinispan Directory have massive performance improvements, and you don't need to necessarily use the versions that are inside of EAP. You can, for example, use the modules provided with JBoss Data Grid which contain newer versions of both Hibernate Search and the Infinispan Directory: 
http://www.jboss.org/products/datagrid/download/.  
Those modules are layered on top of existing EAP Modules and contains a separate 'slot' that you can depend on without conflicting with the internal libraries. Have you tried that route?

Comment: Which of the JGroups backends have you been trying? there is one with a static master choice (by configuration) and one which attempts auto-election but that's experimental. I'll try to help on the Infinispan related question but I'm curious to know which alternatives you've tried.

Comment: We are using the auto-election backend because we need the other node to take over automatically when one node fails.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about which versions are being used. The Infinispan version which is bundled within JBoss EAP is not intended (i.e. tested as extensively as for other purposes) for storing the Lucene index.

When JBoss EAP 6.2 was released, the bundled Infinispan was considered good to go for the internal needs of the application server, but as you might have discovered, the feature of index storage was having at least some performance issues.

In recent developments of Infinispan we applied many improvements to the index storage feature, fixing some bugs and getting very significant performance improvements out of it. I would hope you could be willing to try Infinispan 7.2.0.Beta1 ?
All of these improvements are also being backported to JBoss Data Grid, version 6.5 will make them available as a supported product. Note this feature of storing an Hibernate Search index wasn't supported before - it is going to be a new feature of JDG 6.5.
Modules from JDG 6.5 will be compatible with JBoss EAP, you'll just have to make sure you'll use the Infinispan build provided by JDG and not the one meant for internal usage of EAP.

Performance improvements are still being worked on. It's much better already - especially compared to that older version - but we won't stop working on that yet so if you could try latest bleeding edge versions of Infinispan 7.2.x (another release is scheduled for tomorrow), I'd highly appreciate your feedback to keep pushing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sanne! I tried switching to a newer infinispan version, but it seems that the dependencies are such that I would need to use a newer Hibernate version so I can use a newer Hibernate Search version so I can use a newer Infinispan version. I thought it might not be a good idea to swap out the Hibernate version that comes with the container. Did I miss something there?

Comment: You're right, within upstream projects you would need to upgrade both Infinispan and Hibernate Search, as community updated to Lucene 4.10x. The supported components coming in JDG 6.5 are compatible with Lucene 3.6.x and the EAP included Hibernate versions. You could either try EAP 6.4 (now available and including Hibernate Search) or switch to WildFly 9. We aim to not have such strong version coupling in future, but since it's a new feature the (very) old ones are not going to work.